# How to jump to the next search result in the project tree?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Suppose this file tree. I'm searching for `sass`, and the first highlighted entry is `.sass-cache`. However, I want to navigate to `_sass` instead. Is there any shortcut to jump to the next/previous search result?

I know I could type `_sass` to make it more specific, but I'd still like to know a way to flip through search results if available.

[image: File tree]

Comment: `Up`/`Down` keys. **P.S.** Such search works on already expanded nodes only.

Comment: @LazyOne that is not the case in all views. In the variables view pressing down will expand the node if there is a child that also contains the search term.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is surprisingly intuitive. Just use the arrow keys, Up or down to select the next or previous match

Comment: Can it be customized in `Preferences > Keymap` ?